# Android bounded service getting killed

Tags: android, android-service

I have a bounded service S (seperate process) which gets started when the boot is complete. I have an application A which binds to the service when the application is launched. 
Now my question is when I force stop the application in settings the service S which is in different process also gets destroyed. 
Ideally only the application process should have been killed but the service should have kept running. Why is the service S getting killed even if it is in different process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bound services always stop when the `Activity` that called `bindService()` is destroyed. In order to prevent this from happening you must do the following:

1. Make your service stick by returning `START_STICKY` from the `onStartCommand()` method within your service.
2. You must call `startService()` before calling `bindService()` from your `Activity`.

Comment: I did that but still the service gets killed as soon as unbindService() gets called.

Comment: _You must call startService() before calling bindService() from your Activity_ I'll have situation like this, is it really guaranteed ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to start the service with `START_STICKY`

Answer (score 0):

Bounded service are type of a client server communication. Where it's attached or bounded to the activity with which it's bounded. So the service will be killed.